# React login error message returns undefined on first call then displays error on second call

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, fetch

I'm trying to add some validation based on the firebase error messages. I'm passing the data from the child component to the fetch method in the parent component and if there is an error message, display the message in the child component.

#### Parent Component Fetch Method

```
const sendData = async () => {
    let url;
      if (action === 'LOGIN') {
        url =
          'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyDhbI0X34ZPurUHsRtCas4ybNHgCLQqEfs';
      } else {
        url =
          'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyDhbI0X34ZPurUHsRtCas4ybNHgCLQqEfs';
      }
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(userData),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (!response.ok) {
        // Make error messages user friendly based on firebase error messages.
        if (action === 'LOGIN') {
          authCtx.displayError(data.error.message, 'LOGIN');
          setError(authCtx.errorMessage)
        } else {
          authCtx.displayError(data.error.message, 'SUBMIT');
          setError(authCtx.errorMessage)
        }
        return;
      }
```

#### Context File

```
 const [error, setError] = useState({error:""});

 const displayError = (errorMessage, action) => {
    if (action === 'LOGIN') {
      switch (errorMessage) {
        case 'INVALID_PASSWORD':
          setError('Incorrect password, please try again!');
          break;
        case 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND':
          setError('Email not found in system, please sign up.');
          break;
        case 'INVALID_EMAIL':
          setError("Please don't leave the email field blank!");
          break;
        case 'MISSING_PASSWORD':
          setError("Please don't leave password field blank!");
          break;
        default:
          setError(
            'Too many failed attempts on this account, please wait a few minutes or reset your password to try again!'
          );
          break;
      }
    } else {
      switch (errorMessage) {
        case 'EMAIL_EXISTS':
          setError('Email already exists, please try again or sign in.');
          break;
        case 'MISSING_PASSWORD':
          setError("Please don't leave password field blank!");
          break;
        case 'MISSING_EMAIL':
          setError("Please don't leave the email form blank!");
          break;
        case 'WEAK_PASSWORD : Password should be at least 6 characters':
          setError('Weak password, password should be at least 6 characters!');
          break;
        default:
          setError('Something went wrong, please try again!');
          break;
      }
    }
    console.log(error)
  };


const contextValue = {
    errorMessage: error,
    displayError,
  };
```

If the response is not ok, I'm sending the error message through my context file and setting my error state on the corresponding message. The problem is that the first error message always returns undefined and then the second one contains the original error message.

Example) email: test@test.com, password: password
should return the error message "Email not registered" but returns undefined the first time and when I click it again, it then displays the error. I originally had the switch statement in the fetch (!response.ok) but moved it to a separate file so it displays right away. I feel like it's because on the first render, the state is undefined, but can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I figured it out by running a useEffect hook in the child component and using the error message from the context file as a dependency!

```
useEffect(() => {
// Formatted error is the context error value
    setError(formattedError)
    const showError = setTimeout(() => {
      setError()
    }, 3000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(showError)
    }
  }, [formattedError])
```